# Why does this query returns no result?

Tags: mysql

I have two Tables, the table reseau_stream has different information about my a user post. A user can share the post of someone else. Table reseau_share makes that connexion (you have the detail of both table below). Now, if a user share someone else post, I have to order my query using the datetime of reseau_share.

I don't have alot of MySQL skills, but with some help, I finally ended up with the query below. It is working only if reseau_share has a row in it. If reseau_share is empty, the query return 0 result. I really don't understand why. Can anyone identify why ? Cheers.

### Table reseau_stream

```
id   user_id     content        datetime
1    100         Lorem Ipsum1   2013-03-04 19:35:02
2    100         Lorem Ipsum2   2013-03-04 12:35:02
```

### Table reseau_share

```
 id    user_id     target_id     stream_id    datetime
 -------------------- EMPTY ------------------------
```

### The query

```
SELECT reseau_stream.id,
       reseau_stream.user_id,
       reseau_stream.content,
       IF(reseau_stream.user_id = 100, reseau_stream.datetime, reseau_share.datetime) as datetime 
       FROM reseau_stream, reseau_share 
       WHERE reseau_stream.id 
       IN (
           SELECT id
           FROM reseau_stream
           WHERE user_id = 100
           UNION 
           SELECT stream_id
           FROM reseau_share
           WHERE user_id = 100
        )   ORDER BY  datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Have you labelled your tables incorrectly in the description above? It looks like maybe `reseau_share` and `reseau_stream` have been swapped.

Comment: @FabianTamp Yes you are right, apologies. I fixed it.

Comment: Examples should be reproducible, and there's no stream_id column in either one of your tables.

Comment: @hd1 thanks, it makes 12 hours straight i'm working, I think I should just go to sleep. Can't seem to focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it looks like you need a `LEFT JOIN` on `reseau_share`. Right now you have a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which (a) is causing the zero rows as @diegoperini has pointed out and (b) probably isn't what you really want. It's unclear which column relates the two tables. I'll guess it's `user_id`:

```
SELECT
  reseau_stream.id,
  reseau_stream.user_id,
  reseau_stream.content,
  IF(reseau_stream.user_id = 100, reseau_stream.datetime, reseau_share.datetime) as datetime 
FROM reseau_stream
LEFT JOIN reseau_share ON reseau_stream.user_id = reseau_share.user_id
WHERE reseau_stream.id 
  IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM reseau_stream
      WHERE user_id = 100
      UNION 
      SELECT stream_id -- or whatever 
      FROM reseau_share
      WHERE user_id = 100
  )
ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working as a charm. I'll read a more on the "full outer join" I never heard that before. I'm new to this.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad it worked out! There's a decent tutorial about the different join types [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) and I'm sure there are many more. For just starting out that's a pretty sophisticated query, so you're well on your way :) Bonne chance!

Answer (score 2):

Cartesian product of a non empty set with an empty set is an empty set.

Multiple tables in a `FROM` statement uses above rule to join two tables which ends up with 0 results in your case.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way of bypassing this?